# Where is the search functionality in Apple Music?

Tags: ios, itunes, apple-music

I have just installed the new `iTunes 12.2`, and activated Apple Music through the iPhone app.

Despite the too many buttons on top, it all seems confusing. **I just want a simple search for streamable music.** There is Radio, My Music, New etc.

> But where can I stream an artist I like, who is not shown yet
>   to me through those options?

**Is there a functionality inside iTunes or the Music app in iOS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search directly from the search box in iTunes. Just type artist name and you will get suggestions. You can select the artist name and you will be shown all the songs and albums. There you can stream. Also you can use the iOS Music application search functionality for your favourite artists.

[image]